# Message from webpage : datatables warning: table id

Tags: ajax, error-handling, datatables

I have hosted one website in our company server.
In localhost I can access to all tables fine.
However in the hosted one when I click the link and that page contains tables gives me error:

```
** Message from webpage **
DataTables warning: table id=datatable-questionnaires - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
```

however I don't know how to fix this... how to solve this issue

**edited:**
 `

```
var handleDataTables = function () {
        var catId = $('#catId').val();
        var typeId = $('#typeId').val();
        $('#datatable-questions').dataTable({
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "handlers/_getQuestions.asp?catId=" + catId + "&typeId=" + typeId
            },
            "aoColumns": [
                {
                    "bSortable": false
                }
            ],
            "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) {
                $('#datatable-questions_filter').append(" <button class='btn btn-sm btn-default' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#questionAddModal'>Criar Pergunta</button>");
            }
        }); 


    $('#datatable-users').dataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "handlers/_getUsers.asp?"
        },
        "aoColumns": [
            null,
            null,
            null,
            {
                "bSortable": false
            }
        ],
        "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) {
            $('#datatable-users_filter').append(" <button class='btn btn-sm btn-default' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#userAddModal'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user' aria-hidden='true'></span> Criar Novo</button>");
        }
    });

    $('#datatable-questionnaires').dataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "handlers/_getQuestionnaires.asp?typeId=" + typeId
        },
        "aoColumns": [
            null,
            null,
            null,
            {
                "bSortable": false
            },
            {
                "bSortable": false
            },
            null
        ],
        "fnDrawCallback": function () {
            var $qActivate = $('.qActivate');
            $qActivate.change(function () {
                var isCheck = $(this).is(":checked");
                var id = $(this).data('id');

                jQuery.ajax({
                    data: {
                        id: id,
                        mode: isCheck
                    },
                    url: '../handlers/_activateQuestionnaire.asp',
                    type: 'POST'
                });


            });
        },
        "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) {
            $('#datatable-questionnaires_filter').append(" <a class='btn btn-sm btn-default' href='create_questionnaire.asp'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt' aria-hidden='true'></span> Criar Novo</a>");
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: did you read the page http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7

Comment: @LuckyChingi yes I read it. However the XHR doesn't show anything...

Comment: cant help much if I dont see the code, I would suggest you enable debug mode and see what is throws

Comment: @LuckyChingi the debug mode already is enable.. can't figure damm thing...stupid error :/

Comment: Please post the datatables initialisation code.

Comment: @markpsmith what you mean? I search entire project for datatables and get Matching lines: 35    Matching files: 10    Total files searched: 96

Comment: @markpsmith i.e. `return {

        init: function () {

            handleUploadExcel();
            handleDate();
            handleDataTables();
            handleMultiSelect();
            handleValidations();
            handleAjaxRequests();
            handleJEditable();
            handleExportQuestionnaire();
            handleMisc();


        },

        test: function () {

        }
`

Comment: @markpsmith i run f12 debug this is the code `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--

function datatable-users_onclick() {

}
`

Comment: I would expect some initialisation code along the lines of: `$('#datatable-questionnaires').dataTable(...`

Comment: @markpsmith ok. I edited the post to show you my code

Comment: Look in the Net panel of your browser debugger - look at the datatables request for `_getQuestionnaires.asp`. Is the url correct?